# How do I concatenate a function parameter with multiple strings and variables?

Tags: php, function, parameters, concatenation

This is what the function calls for:

```
create_thumbnail($path, $save, $width, $height);
```

I need to pass a dynamically created $path that contains two variables, $i and $p

This is my code

```
create_thumbnail('images/'.$i.'/coverphoto/'.$p, false, 1160, 574);
```

I know my concatenation of the first parameter is wrong, but I can't seem to get it to work using various different methods of concatenation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include any error messages you recieve when running this script? As from your example code everything looks in order...

Comment: That's the thing that is bugging me, there are no errors anywhere. It just simply does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on my phone so I dont want to type out a bunch of code but ill try help.

$ var = 'images/' . $i . '/coverphoto/' . $p;

Then pass that to your method.